# .exe file with hardware key not running in Linux

Tags: windows, usb-drive, executable, wine

I am running a simulation software in Windows with an `.exe` file and inputs and I also use a usb stick (hardware key) to run the simulation. I want to do the same in Linux.

I downloaded `wine` and gave the command but it gives an error saying:

```
Warning : CHECK THE HARDWARE KEY!
```

It just doesn't recognize the usb stick. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: What software? How does the hardware key work on Windows (is it just a flash drive or what)?

Comment: Does this help? https://superuser.com/a/1477842